# What is the meaning of compiler error message "Polygon is ambigious"

Tags: c++

I'm trying to declare an object in c++:

```
Polygon poly;
```

and the compiler is telling that that "Polygon is ambigious". What does that mean?

Here is the full code:

```
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "point.h" 
#include "Window.h"

using namespace Graph_lib;

int main(int argc, char **argv)   
{  
    Point tl(100,100);

    Simple_window win(tl,600,400,"canvas");

    Axis xa(Axis::x, Point(20,300),280 ,10, "x axis");

    win.attach(xa);
    win.set_label("canvas #2");
    win.wait_for_button();

    Axis ya(Axis::y, Point(20,300),280 ,10, "y axis");
    ya.set_color(Color::cyan);
    ya.label.set_color(Color::dark_red);
    win.attach(ya);
    win.set_label("canvas #3");
    win.wait_for_button();

    Function sine(sin,0,100, Point(20,150),1000,50,50);
    win.attach(sine);
    win.set_label("canvas #4");
    win.wait_for_button();

    sine.set_color(Color::blue);

    Polygon poly; ///ERROR! Ambigious!!!
    poly.add(Point(300,200));
    poly.add(Point(350,100));
    poly.add(Point(400,200));

    poly.set_color(Color::red);
    poly.set_style(Line_style::dash);
    win.attach(poly);
    win.set_label("canvas #5");
    win.wait_for_button();
}
```

As you can see there's a conflict between the user written header, and some header included some where. This is after have recently installed FLTK 1.3.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Graph.cpp
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(45): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'Graph_lib::Color::Transparency' to 'char'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(45): warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(47): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'Graph_lib::Color::Transparency' to 'char'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(47): warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.cpp(65): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.cpp(131): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.cpp(132): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.cpp(389): warning C4800: 'void *' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.cpp(414): warning C4018: '>=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>  GUI.cpp
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(45): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'Graph_lib::Color::Transparency' to 'char'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(45): warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(47): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'Graph_lib::Color::Transparency' to 'char'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(47): warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(107): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(112): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(117): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(130): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>          c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(130) : while compiling class template member function 'Graph_lib::Vector_ref<T>::~Vector_ref(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Graph_lib::Button
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(99) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Graph_lib::Vector_ref<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Graph_lib::Button
1>          ]
1>  Simple_window.cpp
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(45): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'Graph_lib::Color::Transparency' to 'char'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(45): warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(47): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'Graph_lib::Color::Transparency' to 'char'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(47): warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(107): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(112): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(117): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(130): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>          c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(130) : while compiling class template member function 'Graph_lib::Vector_ref<T>::~Vector_ref(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Graph_lib::Button
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(99) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Graph_lib::Vector_ref<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Graph_lib::Button
1>          ]
1>  test.cpp
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(45): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'Graph_lib::Color::Transparency' to 'char'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(45): warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(47): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'Graph_lib::Color::Transparency' to 'char'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(47): warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(107): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(112): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(117): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(36): error C2872: 'Polygon' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(4548) : BOOL Polygon(HDC,const POINT *,int)'
1>          or       'c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(256) : Graph_lib::Polygon'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(36): error C2872: 'Polygon' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(4548) : BOOL Polygon(HDC,const POINT *,int)'
1>          or       'c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(256) : Graph_lib::Polygon'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(36): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'poly'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(36): warning C4551: function call missing argument list
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(36): error C2065: 'poly' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(37): error C2065: 'poly' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(37): error C2228: left of '.add' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(38): error C2065: 'poly' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(38): error C2228: left of '.add' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(39): error C2065: 'poly' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(39): error C2228: left of '.add' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(41): error C2065: 'poly' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(41): error C2228: left of '.set_color' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(42): error C2065: 'poly' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(42): error C2228: left of '.set_style' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(43): error C2065: 'poly' : undeclared identifier
1>  Window.cpp
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(45): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'Graph_lib::Color::Transparency' to 'char'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(45): warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(47): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'Graph_lib::Color::Transparency' to 'char'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(47): warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(107): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(112): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(117): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\window.cpp(74): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\window.cpp(76): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(130): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>          c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\graph.h(130) : while compiling class template member function 'Graph_lib::Vector_ref<T>::~Vector_ref(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Graph_lib::Button
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\gui.h(99) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Graph_lib::Vector_ref<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Graph_lib::Button
1>          ]
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please post some minimal code to reproduce the error, and the compiler error itself.

Comment: Share some more details.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://english.stackexchange.com :) Ambiguous means that it could mean more than one thing, i.e. there is another `someshape` defined somewhere.

Comment: There is conflict with the variable name you are using kindly change the variable name and check.

Comment: @amit Changing the variable name isn't necessary if the OP qualifies it.

Comment: @user3153639 : You might have class name conflict in namespaces.

Comment: What has probably happened is that `Polygon` exists both in the namespace `Graph_lib` and in the global namespace, possibly from two different headers. Because of your line `using namespace Graph_lib;`, the compiler is unable to tell which you mean. You need to qualify it by preceding it with the namespace - either `Graph_lib::Polygon` or `::Polygon`

Answer (score 3):

It means that you've declared two or more entities (types, functions, variables, etc.) called `Polygon`, and the compiler can't tell which you mean in this context.

The complete error message should tell you which declarations are causing the ambiguity. Without seeing them, it's hard to guess how best to fix the error.

**UPDATE**: Now you've posted some code, but not the complete error message or the problematic declarations, I'll hazard a guess that `Polygon` is declared in both the global and `Graph_lib` namespaces. You then dump the whole of `Graph_lib` into the global namespace, making the name ambiguous. If this is the case, then you'll need to specify `::Polygon` or `Grapg_lib::Polygon` to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @user3153639 Please do not edit answers with your code - edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

because there also have a Polygon defined in wingdi.h

[image]

THE SOLUTION IS Put NOGDI in preprocessor. In Visual Studio Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions -> add NOGDI.
[image]

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline there to provide quality answer.